# GLPaint Sample: how to create the view programmatically?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I need to draw something on an image, like in the [GLPaint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328) sample from Apple, but I need to create the EAGL surface where render the OpenGL programmatically.

In the sample is instatiated in the MainWindow.xib

If I try to create the view  programmatically with something like:

```
self.drawingView = [[PaintingView alloc] initWithCoder:nil];
drawingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 380);
[self.view addSubview:drawingView];
```

I got this error:

```
failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6
```

Maybe something related to the init? Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick glance inside the source, Apple have put all of the significant initialisation stuff for PaintingView inside `initWithCoder:`, from lines 77 to 168. That's part of the NSCoding protocol, which is used for archiving and unarchiving objects from files. If you call `initWithCoder:nil`, quite probably the UIView implementation of initWithCoder isn't able to get some relevant value that it needs. At a guess, it probably starts being size zero, which isn't a valid size for a framebuffer object.

I'd suggest you replace `initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` with `initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`, calling the same on super at line 86. For an even better implementation, implement both initWithFrame: and initWithCoder:, having the two call a common section for everything enclosed in the `if((self = [super initWithXXX:argument]))` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a better solution than using a xib and the following code: 
NSArray* nibViews =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PaintingView" owner:self options:nil];

  self.drawingView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];

Comment: Brilliant! Worked for me too!